# Windows installer installs old file

Tags: windows-installer

I created an msi file with Visual Studio 2010. I extract all files from the msi file with msiexec /a and I verify that it contains a text file called version.config. I open this file, and I verify, that it has the latest version.
I install successfully the msi file on a Windows-2003 computer, and I look at the contents of the installed version.config. To my surprise, the old version.config file has been installed! With msiexec /a, I verify again on the test computer that the msi file contains the latest version of the version.config file. I uninstall the application, I verify, that all installed directories are removed, and I reinstall the application. Again, the old version.config file is installed! It seems that the Windows-Installer has somewhere cashed the old version.config file!
This is very bad, because other files' old version might also have been installed without me noticing it!
Why does this happen, and what can I do, so that the msi file installs the latest file versions, and not some cached versions?

I added verbose logging and the following entries are logged concerning the version.config file:

MSI (s) (14:E4) [09:18:57:594]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={B38411CB-AEFB-CD55-F7F7-71CD83323CBD},KeyPath=C:\Unisystems\Runtime\Version.config,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
1: {700E649A-3C70-4C73-965E-2EE7DA72D74C} 2: {B38411CB-AEFB-CD55-F7F7-71CD83323CBD} 3: C:\Unisystems\Runtime\Version.config

MSI (s) (14:E4) [09:19:01:875]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=VERSIO~1.CON|Version.config,SourceCabKey=_26B563DCBD184EACA09AC6F37F1FB178,DestName=Version.config,Attributes=512,FileSize=157,PerTick=32768,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (14:E4) [09:19:01:875]: File: C:\Unisystems\Runtime\Version.config; To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (14:E4) [09:19:01:875]: Source for file '_26B563DCBD184EACA09AC6F37F1FB178' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: Version.config,  Directory: C:\Unisystems\Runtime\,  Size: 157
MSI (s) (14:E4) [09:19:01:875]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Unisystems\Runtime\Version.config

These entries seem to me ok. The size of the log is 3MB, I could upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post an installer log to debug this.  MSI doesn't cache and randomly install old files.  My guess is you have a custom action that's executing during the install that doesn't execute during an admin install and it's influencing the outcome.

Comment: You also need to post more info about the exact scenario. The fact that there is an existing text file means that you may in fact be trying to do an upgrade, and that requires using what VS calls RemovePreviousVersions. It's not uncommon for people to rebuild VS setup files and just run them again, see Repair/Remove and assume that Repair will update the product with the new files in your MSI - it won't!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, after better investigating the setup project, I found a custom action that modified this file. Excuse me for blaming windows installer.